# Auto-terminate C++11 STL thread

Tags: c++, c++11

I want a STL thread to terminate itself after finishing what it's supposed to do; also, is there any way to know when the thread finish? Like an event or so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like a way to poll the completion status of a thread instead of simply blocking with [`join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join), you could spawn your thread with [`async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) and poll the returned [`future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) for completion by [waiting](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) with a 0 timeout:

```
void f() {
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{2});
}

int main() {
  auto const zero = std::chrono::seconds{0};
  auto result = std::async(std::launch::async, f);
  while (result.wait_for(zero) != std::future_status::ready) {
    std::cout << "I'm still waiting...\n" << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{100});
  }
  result.get();
  std::cout << "Done.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

thread wiil be terminate after it's get end of function f, and :

```
void f()
{
    do_some_work();
    // end of function f
}

...
{
    ...
    std::thread t(f);
    do_some_other_work();
    t.join();
}
```

function `join` -> block's your current thread until thread t stops.

Answer (score 1):

The operation is called `join`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/join/

When called, the current thread will **wait** until the other thread finishes. Simple as that. Nothing more.

Comment: I would like to have a C# like behavior, I mean, if I use `join`, the execution will stop until the thread is done, I want that other parts of the code keep running in that time.

Comment: You can have it only in two ways: message queue + message processor OR more threads that run the other jobs while the one is sleeping. Even in C# does this like that, because literally there is no other way to do it. Read about "dispatchers" and "default thread pool" in C# if you don't believe. Here, the simplest way would be to run three threads: one for "other tasks", one for "thread that will end at some point of time" and one for "waiting until the second thread ends". That's the 'thread pool' way.

Comment: Or, if you have **any** message queueing, you can make it post a message from the second thread to the queue, just before it ends. The message processor will notice the message and it's done. That's the 'dispatcher' way.

Answer (score 1):

Like svetlovva and quetzalcoatl said: Use the join operation to ensure a thread is finished.

But if you want to know when a thread is done, without using the blocking join operation, you can detach a thread and use some global vars to check if the thread is alive or not.
Pseudo code:

```
std::atomic<bool> imdone;

void myThreadfunction() {
    //dosomestuff;
    imdone = true;
    return;
}

int main() {
    imdone = false;
    std::thread t1(myThreadfunction);
    t1.detach();

    //dosomeotherstuff

    while(!imdone) {
        //dosomeotherstuffwhilethreadisrunning
    }
}
```

But that's not really nice to use a global var for each thread you want to run independently…